# Xamarin.iOS How to get installation id after registering to backend for push notifications

Tags: azure, xamarin.ios, apple-push-notifications

I am trying to obtain the installation id of the client app/device after registering to the backend (web API hosted in Azure and using Notification Hub) for push notifications. There are multiple methods that give an installation id and I am not sure which is the correct one.

As I understand, the installation id is valid as long as the application stays installed on the device, if its deleted and reinstalled a new installation id is assigned to the device is this correct? If not please advise about the life cycle of the installation id.

```
private async Task SendRegistrationToServerAsync(NSData deviceToken)
        {
            //this is the template/payload used by iOS. It contains the "messageParam"
            // that will be replaced by our service

            const string templateBodyAPNS = @"{
                                                ""aps"" : {
                                                    ""alert"" : ""$(messageParam)"",
                                                    ""mutable-content"": 1
                                                },
                                            }";


            var templates = new JObject();
            templates["genericMessage"] = new JObject
            {
                {"body", templateBodyAPNS }
            };

            // send registration to web api hosted in Azure
            var client = new MobileServiceClient(MyApp.App.MobileServiceUrl);
            await client.GetPush().RegisterAsync(deviceToken, templates);

            //get the installation id (not sure if this is the correct way)
            Console.WriteLine("Installation id: " + client.InstallationId.ToString());
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are right.

According to https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/writingdata_services/2016/01/22/adding-push-notification-tags-from-an-azure-mobile-apps-client/#comments:

> The installation ID is a GUID that is specific to an installed app on
>   a given mobile device, to the point that when you uninstall and
>   reinstall the app on the same device you get a new GUID.

And the `installation ID` can be obtained from the Mobile client API:`MobileServiceClient.InstallationId;`

Comment: InstallationId is not a static property